# Visual Studio can't debug, can only attach

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I cannot press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug my program, because there is only an <kbd>Attach...</kbd> button instead of a <kbd>Debug</kbd> button.

I am using a .c source file, and I was able to debug my sources until I changed a .cpp to a .c and now every source file I open, it says "Attach...". What do I do?

Comment: Perhaps you renamed this file outside the VS project? You need to make sure that the new file is the one linked to your project. If you still have 'a.cpp' in the project, then remove it, and drag 'a.c' into the same location instead.

Comment: Did you open the project? It's not sufficient to load the source file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try menu *Tools* → *Customize* → *Commands* → *Add command...[button]* → *Debug* (under *Categories*). Find and add the button you would like to.

Also try setting your project to startup one - in Solution Explorer - right click on the project and choose the *Set as Startup* project option.

Comment: Simply setting the project as start up project did it for me.

Comment: My solution didn't have a startup project, so good call!  This should be it's own answer.

Comment: Does not work for me. the debugger command also shows as attach