# Opening cpp files or visual studio 2013 ultimate dosen't have debug option neither error list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When i open a cpp file i have created (that isn't inside a project) in visual studio 2013 ultimate, i see an option that says attach instead of the usual debug if i open a c++ project.
Also no error list etc shows. How to fix that so visual studio always defaults to the c++ editor (or IDE)?

This question and answers are not what problem i am experiencing: [Visual Studio Can't Debug Can Only Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210847/visual-studio-cant-debug-can-only-attach)

Comment: You need to create a project for either of these to work. You can not just build c++ files without a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to use the c++ compiler while using visual studio is to create a `new project` and then choose `win32` application.

After that you can add your files e.g. `cpp` or `header` files.

If you want to e.g. download a `cpp` file online and have an option to compile it then the only way to do so would be to either copy the code to lets say a `cpp` that you have **inside** your project or copy the **whole** `cpp` file into the project.

You can't just open the `cpp` file and have an option to compile it in *visual studio* like you could with lets say *dev c++.*